Movie like "Lord of the Flies" with boys trapped in a dark, sinister place, possibly a basement or a sewer
I'm trying to find a movie I watched around 2014. It was in English and seemed to be American. I don’t remember the exact genre, but I think it might be a psychological thriller. The main plot involved a group of boys trapped in a dark and sinister place, possibly a basement or a sewer, with at least two rooms. It seemed like they were locked in and couldn't escape.
I’m not sure if there were any girls, but I don’t think so. The boys each took on roles, kind of like in "Lord of the Flies," but I can’t remember the roles for everyone. The only one I recall clearly is a boy who slowly begins to transform—he lets his hair grow out, starts wearing female clothing and makeup, and becomes more feminine.
Eventually, the other boys start abusing and raping him, seemingly driven by a need for dominance or sexual urges. It was a very disturbing and emotional scene, set in a dark room with a dirty, old mattress.
I know it's not much to go on, but I’ve been searching for this movie for ages. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it!

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535616/? Similar themes here

I know it probably isn’t the movie you’re thinking of, but your question reminds me of The Wild Boys (2017), which is a truly unique movie about boys being taken to an island as punishment for a similar assault. I won’t spoil the ending, but you could certainly that there are similar themes.

What language did you watch it in?  Did it seem foreign to your home country?

@ParkerMacInnis pretty sure it was english spoken, looked American like. But tbh not 100% sure

Since it was a while ago when you saw it, those child actors would have grown up.  Do you know anything else they were in since then?  Or any distinct features the kids had?

There’s not a lot to go on here, but it might be Das Experiment (2001), which is one of many films based on the famous 1971 “Stanford Experiment”, a simulated prison experiment where a group of volunteers are assigned roles as guards and prisoners.
The film has scenes where prisoners are humiliated, and at least one is forced into feminization as a means of degradation by the guards.
It might also be worth checking out the American remake, The Experiment (2010), starring Adrien Brody and Forest Whitaker.

All characters in Das Experiment are very much adults though.

Good guess, sadly it isn't the movie i'm looking for.
